# Using one and all chaining in Restangular post requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, restangular

I have an issue where I'm trying to make a post request using Restangular:

I'll setup the query like so:

```
var auth = Restangular.all('auth');
var check = auth.one('check');
```

Then I'll do the post request like so:

```
var user = {
  email: 'randomemail@gmail.com',
  pass: 'randompass'
}

check.post(user)
```

However, the request shows an error, when I check the network, the request is sent as so :

```
http://localhost/auth/check/[object object]
```

Why does the post request attach the object like a query parameter instead of sending it in the request body?

If i'm formatting this post request incorrectly, can someone point out the correct way to format a post request using one and all in Restangular.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post to a `one()`, `post()` is actually expecting a subElement as the first argument, which is why it's attaching the object passed to the path...

(from [documentation](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#element-methods))

> **post(subElement, elementToPost, [queryParams, headers])**: Does a POST
>   and creates a subElement. Subelement is mandatory and is the nested
>   resource. Element to post is the object to post to the server

To post to `/auth/check`, you can use `customPOST()`...

```
auth.customPOST(user, 'check');
```

Edit - Here are a couple of examples if you are set on using `post()`...

```
Restangular.one('auth').post('check', user);
```

Or

```
auth.all('check').post(user);
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you might do it without having to use customPOST?

Comment: Updated with examples. Is there a reason why you don't want to use customPOST?

Comment: I understand your point, I'm still a little confused as to why the following wouldn't work: ```Restangular.all('auth').post('check', user);```